# problema al restaurar una Base de Datos

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Tengo que restaurar una bd en **postgresql**, con un archivo **`dump`** y al ejecutar el script me da un error aqui:

> 1 1 Default Nomenclature 1 2018-06-08 21:33:01.779138 2018-06-08
>   21:33:01.779138 always
>
> ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «1» LINE 21598: 1 1 Default
>   Nomenclature 1 2018-06-08 21:33:01.779138 2018-0... ^
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «1» SQL state: 42601 Character:
>   514753

intente un par de cosas y google, pero no encontré la solución

Comment: es un proyecto que tengo que arreglar, me enviaron el dump como una copia de la bd es de nombre dump de tipo archivo postgresql(.sql), y de comando no estoy usando ninguno, copie y pegue el contenido en el sql editor de pdadmin y lo ejecuto desde ahi, lo estare haciendo mal?

Comment: intenta con el comando `pg_restore -d base_datos  -dump.sql`

Comment: puedes acceder con pgadmin y ir verificando la creacion de la base de datos, lo otro es que aveces el comando esta mal y la consola no te dice nada y el -dump.sql esta mal es solo dump.sql

Comment: puedes agregar el comando (colocando servidor dummy y clave dummy de ser necesaria)  y agregar el error que dices

Comment: alli ejecuto el backup, no veo nada de error eso es  normal cuando se ejecuta ese comando has un select en el schema en cualquier tabla

Comment: no te preocupes , agrega la respuesta explicala un poco y borra los comentarios innecesarios

Comment: finalmente realice la restauracion de dump.sql con el comando bin>psql -U openpg -d openpg -f dump.sql , pero la bd continua con el error de sintaxis, no encuentro forma de poder solucionarlo

Comment: Hazlo con pg_restore